# I have an ERROR in Flutter that i dont know how to fix

Tags: flutter

I am a begginer in flutter coding and i have no idea what to do here...also i am using Linux Manjaro.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQqZ.png)

Comment: `Insufficient storage` doesnt ring a bell to you ?

Comment: what do i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: `Insufficient storage`.

You need to check your free space in your system. Or clear some cache in app.

Comment: yes i realised that but i downloaded this android emulator in konsole in manjaro and i dont have Android studio so dont know how to clean in in konsole

Comment: Try to use `adb shell` to get into device shell. Run the following command: `cmd package list packages|cut -d":" -f2|while read package ;do pm clear $package;done`.

Comment: Can you check my answer as right, please?